# Session expire for popup aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have query over session expire on popup aspx page.

I have asp.net project where session expire functionality is working. now i have add one new aspx that will open as popup on certain

event on the login page after sign-in process.

Now question is session expire functionality will also work for the popup aspx page as it inherit same namespace OR

we need to implement some thing else for this

Comment: The built in `HttpSession` is bound to the user and application, so all web pages within the application will share the same session for the user and will be affected if the session expires. Your question is very vague. Please clarify what you want to achieve and what you have implemented so far. Post relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you include within your asxp code.
If you include the code for the session expires within the popup it will also run. If not, it will not run on the popup.